# Why Jpa sorting is not working with Pageable in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Paging is working good but I cannot sort the data according to a specific field.
My repository method `Page<AdvertSearch> findAll(Pageable pageable);`

My entity class is:

```
public class AdvertSearch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    private String id;

    private String advertId;
    private String officeId;
    private String officeName;

    //TODO: type hangi Point olacak hangi class olacak karar verilecek
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "POINT SRID 4326")
    private Point location;

    private OfficeType officeType;
    private String city;
    private String district;
    private String mainOfficeId;
    private Integer facilityCount;
    private Integer virtualPackageCount;
    private BuildingType buildingType;
    private Integer securityCount;
    private Double monthlyPrice;
    private String currency;
    private Integer capacity;

    //TODO: officelerde rating olmayacak diye konustuk bunun da netlestirilmesi gerek
    private Double rating;
    private Integer ratingCount;
}
```

My postman request is: `http://localhost:8080/advertsearch/findallbypage?page=0&size=4&sort=district&direction=desc`

[image]

As you see I want to sort the data according to district but it is not working. Is my request wrong ? Or is it about `Pageable` in JPA ?

Comment: Can you add the relevant part from your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction should be in the sort param :

`?page=0&size=4&sort=district,desc`

You can find more examples [here](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-pagination-sorting-example/)